# Does ant-design-mobile work with create-react-native-app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, antd, create-react-native-app

I need to add  `{"plugins": [["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile" }]]}` to `.babelrc` from a project generated by **create-react-native-app** to make [ant-design-mobile](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile/blob/master/docs/react/introduce.en-US.md#%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85) work in react native.

I have started a new project with **create-react-native-app**.
Change the .babelrc to this:

```
 {
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source",
      ]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile" }]
  ]
}
```

Class:

```
import { Button } from 'antd-mobile';

export class Screen extends React.Component<any,{}>{
   render(){
     return(
            <View>
                <Button>Something</Button>
            </View>
        )
   }
}
```

However, I'm still getting this error on start:

```
Note: must use https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import .
For more information, please see https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile/issues/602
```

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at official react-native app demo: https://github.com/ant-design/antd-mobile-samples/tree/master/react-native

Comment: thanks . The problem seems to be that I have to run `eject` in order to use  `babel-plugin-import` for projects generated by `create-react-native-app`, which is something I want to avoid.